# req.body undefined for Post register User

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to register use with Post endpoint `req.body` is undefined and I don't know why because endpoints for products work ok.
model of User

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  login: { type: String, require: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

register endpoint

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { login, password } = sanitize(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    const isLogin = login && typeof login === 'string';
    const isPassword = password && typeof password === 'string';
    const isDataValid = isLogin && isPassword;

    if (isDataValid) {
      const userWithLogin = await User.findOne({ login });
      if (userWithLogin) {
        return res
          .status(409)
          .json({ message: 'User with this login already exists' });
      }
      const user = new User({
        login,
        password: await bcrypt.hash(password, 10),
      });
      await user.save();
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created ' + user.login });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Bad request' });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` doesn't I'm using `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Could you help me find an error?

Comment: If `req.body` is undefined you're not adding the body parser middleware in the correct place (for example _after_ your routes).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using express you have to give permission to use json , following code might work

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express.app();

app.use(express.json());    //this two line must be included for parsing data in body 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body)     // this will send data of req.body
});
```

Comment: If _any_ body parser middleware is added in the correct place, `req.body` will be an empty object and not undefined. So this won't solve the issue.